# Does osm2po find routes of alternating modes e.g. car, ferry, car

Tags: routing, osm2po

I loaded europe-latest.pbf into osm2po using the default osm2po.config and

java -Xmx8g -jar ../osm2po-4.6.9/osm2po-core-4.6.9-signed.jar prefix=eu tileSize=x,c ../europe-latest.osm.pbf

and looked at car routes that must use ferries, e.g. Dover to Calais or between Athens and the greek Islands etc.

osm2po doesn't find any route.

Does any else observe this, too?

How should I proceed to make osm2po also find these kinds of routes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the osm2po perspective there is no difference between ferries and normal roads.

Have a look into the config:

```
wtr.tag.route.ferry =            2,  1, 10,  ferry
wtr.tag.route.shuttle_train =    2,  2, 50,  rail|car
wtr.tag.railway.rail =           3,  3, 50,  rail

wtr.allow.motor[car|_vehicle].[yes|destination] = car
```

There might be a few reasons why osm2po ignores them:

1. Mostly because they are connected via highway=service which is not enabled by default. But please be careful, including all services will blow up and slow down your routing.
2. Sometimes ferries and shuttle trains are tagged correctly in OSM but have no connection to the road network.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the advice. Could you adivse me on how to use "highway=service" properly? Like this: wtr.tag.highway.service =       1, 51, 25,   car|ferry

Comment: I did it as specified and it now works, for my Dover Calais and Greek Islands examples. Thank you, osm2po is really impressive.